# How do I list the constraints of a DOMAIN?

Tags: postgresql, constraint, system-tables, catalogs, domain

Consider the following scenario:

```
CREATE DOMAIN dom_zipcode AS text;
ALTER DOMAIN dom_zipcode
  ADD CONSTRAINT zipchk CHECK (char_length(VALUE) = 5);
```

Now, if I want to drop that constraint with [`ALTER DOMAIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdomain.html), [The manual says](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdomain.html):

```
ALTER DOMAIN name
    DROP CONSTRAINT [ IF EXISTS ] constraint_name [ RESTRICT | CASCADE ]
```

But how can we find `constraint_name`? `\dD` only shows the constraint's definition (`CHECK` statement).

```
\dD dom_zipcode ;
                             List of domains
 Schema |    Name     | Type | Modifier |             Check
--------+-------------+------+----------+--------------------------------
 public | dom_zipcode | text |          | CHECK (char_length(VALUE) = 5)
(1 row)
```

I can dump the schema using `pg_dump`, but I believe there must exist a more elegant way to establish this using the `psql` terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## PostgreSQL's System Catalog

```
SELECT conname
FROM pg_constraint
WHERE contypid = 'dom_zipcode'::regtype;
```

Comment: Thanks. I still wonder why the name is not visible from within the domain.

Comment: Because they are getting data from the function to get only constraints. If you run psql -E you'll be able to get queries does when doing \d commands. The function `pg_catalog.pg_get_constraintdef()` is run

Comment: Really good answer. =)

Comment: Someone should make a patch to allow `\dD` to show domain constraints.

Answer (score 0):

## SQL Spec's `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.DOMAIN_CONSTRAINTS`

You can also query this in [`domain_constraints` table of the `information_schema`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-domain-constraints.html)

```
SELECT FORMAT('%I.%I.%I', constraint_schema, constraint_catalog, constraint_name)
FROM information_schema.domain_constraints
WHERE (domain_catalog,domain_schema,domain_name) = ('test','public','dom_zipcode');
```

Answer (score 0):

**this query outputs exactly what pgsql shows.**

```sql
SELECT nsp.nspname                   as "Schema",
       typ.typname                   as "Name",
       tt.typname                    as "Type",
       pc.collname                   as "Collation",
       typ.typnotnull                as "Nullable",
       typ.typdefault                as "Default",
       con.conname                   as "Constraint Name",
       pg_get_constraintdef(con.oid) as "Constraint Definition"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_type typ
         inner join pg_catalog.pg_namespace nsp ON nsp.oid = typ.typnamespace
         inner join pg_catalog.pg_type tt on typ.typbasetype = tt.oid
         left join pg_collation pc on typ.typcollation = pc.oid
         left JOIN pg_catalog.pg_constraint con ON con.contypid = typ.oid
WHERE nsp.nspname = '<Schema Name>'
  and typ.typtype = 'd';
```

test this by creating two domains :

```
create domain type1 varchar default 0 not null
    constraint ss check ( value in ('ff')) COLLATE "af-NA-x-icu";

create domain type2 int default null;
```

**psql output:**

[image]

**query output:**

[image]